# Need to get ID from user_items table LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I have a table named `user_items` which holds this info: `id`, `user_id`, `item_id`

Currently I can get user items from `items` table like this:

```
public function userItem()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','user_items','user_id','item_id');
}
```

And in my HTML I do this:

`@foreach(Auth::user()->userItem as $item)`

But now I want to get `id` column from `user_items` table and I have a problem.
If I do this in
`User` model

```
public function sellItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserItem');
}
```

and in HTML like this:

```
 @foreach(Auth::user()->sellItem as $itemId)   
 <a href="/sell-item/{{$itemId->id}}" class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="text-decoration: none">Sell for {{$item->price/2}} <img src="/img/gold.png"></a><br>
 @endforeach
```

It duplicates my HTML as many times as many items are in `user_items` which belongs to the user. So the question is how to avoid duplicating and only get `Auth::user()->sellItem ID` and place it into url ?

This is full HTML

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->userItem as $item)
    <img src="{{$item->img}}">
     <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
 {{$item->title}}<br> 

 @foreach(Auth::user()->sellItem as $itemId) // THIS DUPLICATES THE BUTTON  
 <a href="/sell-item/{{$itemId->id}}" class="btn-sm btn-danger" style="text-decoration: none">Sell for {{$item->price/2}} <img src="/img/gold.png"></a><br>
 @endforeach

 <p>{{$item->description}}</p>
     </span> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sorry but i dont get it. You want your html to show only 1 item,which is the sell item or you want to show only the ID of the item? Did you also have a sellItem table ?

Comment: No. Right now all items are displayed that user has bought. Now I need to sell them. But to sell them I need to get `id` from `user_items`, but currently I'm getting `item_id` from that table. I do not know how to get `id` from `user_items` any other way @j.Doe

Comment: oh i get it. Because u use another foreach in there thats why it loops as many item as the user have. You should drop the loop. As for user_items id, you already do a looping `@foreach(Auth::user()->userItem as $item)` so you should just use `$item->id` in your url.

Comment: @j.Doe It doesn't work because then I get the `id` of item which is stored in `items` table not in `user_items` table

Comment: @j.Doe the `user model`: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','user_items','user_id','item_id');`

Comment: you have a user_items table right? so `$item->id` should return the id from that table and not items table but if your user_items table's item has same id as items table's id. Then of course the id will be the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149880/discussion-between-feknaz-and-j-doe).

Comment: But maybe your logic is wrong. i think it should be `User hasMany App\User_items` in User model and `user_items belongsTo App\User` in user_items model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a many-to-many relationship.

User has many Items and Items belong to many User so userItem table act as a bridge in between the 2 table.

in order to do this in laravel, you should do it this way in userItem.php

userItem.php:

```
public function item() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Item'); 
} 

public function User() 
{ 
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 
}
```